# C#で作ったCOM dll内の配列にはどのようにアクセスすればよいか

Tags: c#, vba, com

C#でExcel VBAからアクセスするようのDLLを作りました。

```
[Guid("6905A3B9-E09A-492A-9EC8-2A558814F778")]
public class Test
{
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
    public Test() { Items = new Item[0]; }

    public void GetItems(out Item[] items)
    {
        items = new Item[2];
        Items[0] = new Item() { ID = 1, Name = "A" };
        Items[1] = new Item() { ID = 2, Name = "B" };
    }
}
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

このdllに対して、GetItems()のout引数であるitemsをVBA側で取得したいです。
app.GetItemsのout変数部分をどのように書けばよいか...

```
 Public Sub Test()
 Dim app As Object
 Set app = CreateObject("Test")
 'ここをどうやって書けばよいか... > app.GetItems(out変数を取得したい)

 End Sub
```

dllはCOM用にビルドされており、VBA側で参照設定できる or CreateObject()でオブジェクトが作成はできています。すごく初歩的な質問でしたらすみません。
ご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`UnmanagedType.SafeArray`の例](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype?view=net-6.0#examples)を読む限り

> ```
> public void GetItems(out Item[] items)
> ```

この部分を

```
public void GetItems([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)] ref Item[] items)
```

と書くことでVBA側は

```
Dim items As Item()
app.GetItems(items)
```

と書けるかもしれません。

なお試してません。他の部分でエラーになるかもですし、メソッド引数で配列を受け取る形はあまり見かけない気がします。

Comment: ご教授ありがとうございます。試してみます！